# Why don't get the expected result despite the high accuracy rate?

Tags: cross-validation, svm, overfitting, genetic-algorithms

I have a database of images of 213 examples (7 classes). First, I extracted the features where I got 212 features. CAD, I maintain a data matrix of 213x212. I used the genetic algorithm for both optimize SVM hyperparameters and feature selection (with binary chromosome). For this, i **divided my dataset to training set (75%) and test set (25%)**. In each chromosome, i calculate fitness function based on test set accuracy **(i never use test set for training)**. I noticed that the recognition rate in each generation increases, where i finally got a accuracy rate equal to 98%. **The problem is when I test the SVM model on other images, I don't get the expected result**. Is this an over-learning problem? someone can help me?

**Edit 1**: I used a Gabor filter to extract the features from this 213 images. I obtained 50,000 features, I then reduce the number of dimensions with PCA in order to obtain 212 features (with the retention of 99% of information).

Comment: You seem to have an awful lot of parameters for a data set with just 213 observations and seven classes, so I absolutely could believe that you’ve overfit.

Comment: what do you offer as a solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Regularise appropriately and use repeated cross-validation.

Comment: I read on the repeated cross validation, but how i can use repeated  cross validation in my case. By changing the learningSet randomly  in each generation ???